# Trigonometry: Height of a Tree

Tags: trigonometry

Each of two observers 325 feet apart measures the angle of elevation to the top of a tree that sits on the straight line between them. These angles are 45° and 32°, for observers A and B, respectively. (Give your answers as decimals to tenth.)

a) What is the height of the tree?

b) How far is the base of its trunk from each observer?

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: I have drawn the diagram and solved the entire triangle, but I don't know where to go from there.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can form two right triangles with one common side, that's the tree height. So you have:

$$\tan 45^{\circ} \cdot a = \tan 32^{\circ} \cdot b$$

$a,b$ are the distances from each observer to the tree. Now use that $a = 325- b$ and $\tan 45^{\circ} = 1$. The rest should be easy, right?